# How to compile all descendants in a nested hierarchy

Tags: javascript, extendscript

I'm having a hard time conceptualizing how best to compile a list of decendents of an array of parents.  I have a hierarchy that looks something like this, but the tree could get more complex:

```
[
    {parent: 'e', children: ['f']},
    {parent: 'b', children: ['c','d']},
    {parent: 'd', children: ['e']},
    {parent: 'a', children: ['b']},
    {parent: 'c', children: ['d]'}
]
```

And I would like an output something like this:

```js
[
    {parent: 'e', children: ['f']},
    {parent: 'b', children: ['c','d','e','f']},
    {parent: 'd', children: ['e','f']},
    {parent: 'a', children: ['b','c','d','e','f']},
    {parent: 'c', children: ['d','e','f']},
]
```

Ideally the answer would not use any modern javascript since I am writing this in extendscript which is based on ECMA-262 from 1999.  Yea I know it's painful, so I'll take whatever I can get and I'll make it work.

edit: as bergi noticed, circular references are allowed.  So `a` can be a child of `b` and `b` can be a child of `a` because they can modify different attributes of each other.

Comment: So you don't want only grandchildren, but all descendants?

Comment: What are `a`, `b`, `c` etc? Are they strings, numbers, objects?

Comment: This is not a tree. `d` has multiple parents.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt, please? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes, all descendents.  I corrected my question.  Thanks

Comment: https://babeljs.io/repl

Comment: Did you get an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Well... sorry it looks quite cryptic, almost like COBOL, but it works (I hope):

```
// data -------------------------------------------------------------

var array =[
    {parent: 'e', children: ['f']},
    {parent: 'b', children: ['c','d']},
    {parent: 'd', children: ['e']},
    {parent: 'a', children: ['b']},
    {parent: 'c', children: ['d']}
]


// main -------------------------------------------------------------

var obj = array_to_obj(array); 

while(obj.toSource() != spread_children(obj).toSource())
    // repeat the function until there aren't changes in the obj anymore
    obj = spread_children(obj);

array = obj_to_array(obj); // <-- result is here

// output, just to be sure
var msg = "\n[\n"
for (var i in array)
    msg += "  " + array[i].toSource().slice(1,-1) + ",\n";
alert(msg+"]");


// functions --------------------------------------------------------

function array_to_obj(array) { // [{a:[]},{b:[]}] --> {a:{},b:{}}
    var obj = {};
    for (var i in array) {
        var key = array[i].parent;
        var value = children_to_objects(array[i].children);
        obj[key] = value;
    }
    return obj;

    function children_to_objects(array) { // [a,b,c] --> {a:'a',b:'b',c:'c'}
        var obj = {};
        for (var i in array) obj[array[i]] = array[i];
        return obj;
    }
}

function spread_children(obj) {        // a little bit cryptic...
    for (var key in obj) {             // for all keys of the obj
        for (var value in obj[key]) {  // for all values of the key
            if (obj[value]) {          // if obj[value] (parent) exists:
                // add all keys of the obj[value] to obj[key]
                for (var v in obj[value]) obj[key][v] = v;
                // and since object can't have identical keys
                // there will never be duplicates
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

function obj_to_array(obj) { // {a:{},b:{}} --> [{a:[]},{b:[]}]
    var array=[];
    for (var parent in obj) {
        var children = [];
        for (var child in obj[parent]) children.push(child);
        array.push({'parent': parent, 'children': children});
    }
    return array;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Did you use [the outdated and deprecated `toSource` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource) on purpose, to avoid a more modern solution?

Comment: Exactly. Because this is Extendscript. Of course you can use something like this [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) and `JSON.stringify()` then. But I wanted to show a 'pure' solution. Or you can write a dedicated function to compare two objects, but that would make the script even more uglier.

Comment: Thanks Yuri!  I tried your script in after effects and got a `undefined is not an object` error on line 41 `var obj = {};` which doesn't make sense.  I looked around there and couldn't find anything out of place.  But your code gave me some ideas to incorporate into code I've already written.  In particular, using object keys avoid duplicates is a novel approach I never thought of.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know next to nothing about AE (you never mentioned AE in your question). Probably there are some features uncommon with InDesign. Say, the error could has to do with naming (the same name inside the same function). I'd try to change the name to `obj1 = {}`. Which is has little sense as well, but anyway.

Comment: Yea Yuri, that's the first thing I tried.  I'll figure it out.  My biggest problem was conceptualizing how to go about it, but your script helped me understand what I need to do now.  Thanks again!

Comment: I've got an idea, why there was the error in AE. Try to change the `for (var i in array)` with classic `for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++)`